# Recursion Formula Euler Numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to derive the formula
$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n\choose 2k}E_k = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}^2E_k=0$$

Where $E_k$ are the Euler Numbers.

The approach that I have taken is to first prove that ${2n\choose 2k} = {n\choose k}^2$.  I looked into applying Pascal's Rule, but that got me nowhere.

I also have already proven that $E_{2n+1} = 0$ for $n=1,2,...$  I feel like this will come into play when I attempt to prove that the sequence is equal to $0$.

Comment: You can't prove $\binom{2n}{2k}=\binom{n}{k}^2$, since it is not true. Check $n=2,k=1$.

Comment: Alright, so what approach should I take on this problem?